# find all of price that starts with "~" symbol in list then print it out python webscraping output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used beautifulsoup to find this :

```
d = soup1.find_all(attrs={"class": "topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle"})
d
```

the output of this is :

```
[<p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle">
 Tanjong Pagar
 <span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data-latitude="1.279826" data-longitude="103.8473171"></span>
 · ~$20/pax
 </p>,
 <span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data-latitude="1.279826" data-longitude="103.8473171"></span>,
 <p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle--alt">
 Breakfast &amp; Brunch, Craft Beer, Sandwiches
 </p>,
 <p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle">
 Amoy Street
 <span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data-latitude="1.2821927" data-longitude="103.847759"></span>
 · ~$40/pax
```

how can i extract or find all the price in this list, **eg. "~$40/pax"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.compile` in `soup.find_all`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
s = """<p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle">
 Tanjong Pagar
 <span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data-latitude="1.279826" data-longitude="103.8473171"></span>
 · ~$20/pax
 </p>
 <span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data-latitude="1.2821927" data-longitude="103.847759"></span>
 · ~$40/pax"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
for i in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"\~\$\d+\/pax")):
    print(i.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
· ~$20/pax
· ~$40/pax
```